# Python:New line at the same postion

Tags: python, python-2.7, newline, carriage-return

In python 2.7 how can you achieve the following feature:

```
print "some text here"+?+"and then it starts there"
```

the output on terminal should look like:

```
some text here
              and then it starts here
```

I have searched around and I think `\r`should do the work but I tried it out it does not work. I am confused now.

BTW, is the `\r` solution portable?

P.S.
In my odd situation, I think knowing the length of prev line is quite difficult for me. so any idea rather then using the length of the line above it?

==================================================================================

Okay the situation is like this, I am writing a tree structure and I want to print it out nicely using the __str__ function

```
class node:
def __init__(self,key,childern):
    self.key = key
    self.childern = childern

def __str__(self):
    return "Node:"+self.key+"Children:"+str(self.childern)
```

where Children is a list.

Every time it is printing Children, I want it indented using one more than last line. So I think I cannot predict the length before the line I want to print.

Comment: Did you try that on Windows?

Comment: \r returns the caret to the beginning of the line, it doesn't seem like that's what you're looking for

Comment: @dorafmon you mention in a comment below that you don't have information on the line before it. Can you explain why that is? Can you give more details on your particular use-case? I don't think we can help you otherwise.

Comment: @dorafmon are you outputting your lines to stdout? or to a file?

Comment: @entropy I edited it again.

Comment: @entropy I am printing it to stdout

Answer (score 5):

`\r` is probably not a portable solution, the way it is rendered will depend on whatever text editor or terminal you're using. On older Mac systems, `'\r'` is was used as the end of line character(On windows it is `'\r\n'` and on linux and OSX it is `'\n'`.

You could simply do something like this:

```
def print_lines_at_same_position(*lines):
    prev_len = 0
    for line in lines:
        print " "*prev_len + line
        prev_len += len(line)
```

Usage example:

```
>>> print_lines_at_same_position("hello", "world", "this is a test")
hello
     world
          this is a test
>>>
```

This will only work if whatever you're outputting to has a font with a fixed character length though. I can't think of anything that will work otherwise

**Edit to fit changed question**

Okay, so that's an entirely different question. I don't think there's any way to do it with it starting at *exactly* the position where the last line left off unless `self.key` has a predictable length. But you can get something pretty close with this:

```
class node:
    def __init__(self,key,children):
        self.key = key
        self.children = children
        self.depth = 0

    def set_depth(self, depth):
        self.depth = depth
        for child in self.children:
            child.set_depth(depth+1)

    def __str__(self):
        indent = " "*4*self.depth
        children_str = "\n".join(map(str, self.children))
        if children_str:
            children_str = "\n" + children_str
        return indent + "Node: %s%s" % (self.key, children_str)
```

Then just set the depth of the root node to 0 and do that again every time you change the structure of the tree. There are more efficient ways if you know exactly how you're changing the tree, you can probably figure those out yourself :)

Usage example:

```
>>> a = node("leaf", [])
>>> b = node("another leaf", [])
>>> c = node("internal", [a,b])
>>> d = node("root", [c])
>>> d.set_depth(0)
>>> print d
Node: root
    Node: internal
        Node: leaf
        Node: another leaf
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the len("text") * ' ' to get the amount of white space you want.

To get a portable line break, use os.linesep

```
>>> import os
>>> os.linesep
'\n'
```

EDIT

Another option that might be suitable in some cases is to override the stdout stream.

```
import sys, os

class StreamWrap(object):

        TAG = '<br>' # use a string that suits your use case

        def __init__(self, stream):
                self.stream = stream

        def write(self, text):
                tokens = text.split(StreamWrap.TAG)
                indent = 0
                for i, token in enumerate(tokens):
                        self.stream.write(indent*' ' + token)
                        if i < len(tokens)-1:
                                self.stream.write(os.linesep)
                        indent += len(token)

        def flush(self):
                self.stream.flush()

sys.stdout = StreamWrap(sys.stdout)

print "some text here"+ StreamWrap.TAG +"and then it starts there"
```

This will give you a result like this:

```
>>> python test.py 
some text here
          and then it starts there
```

Comment: sorry but this cannot solve my question because I can not get the information on the line before it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `os.linesep` to get a more portable linebreak, instead of just `\r`. I would then use `len()` to calculate the length of the 1st string in order to calculate whitespace.

```
>>> import os
>>> my_str = "some text here"
>>> print my_str + os.linesep + ' ' * len(my_str) + 'and then it starts here'
some text here
              and then it starts here
```

The key is `' ' * len(my_str)`. This will repeat the space character `len(my_str)` times.

Answer (score 0):

The `\r` solution is not what you are looking for since it is part of the windows newline, but in mac systems it actually is the newline.

You would need code like the following:

```
def pretty_print(text):
    total = 0
    for element in text:
        print "{}{}".format(' '*total, element)
        total += len(element)

pretty_print(["lol", "apples", "are", "fun"])
```

Which will print the lines of text the way you want them to.